# Run playbook on group specified via prompt?

Tags: ansible

I would like to run playbook on specified group of servers via interactive selections during play.
I have all groups defined in inventory file.
I would like to select the proper group via interactive session via prompt during play, e.g., via `vars_prompt`.

From my understanding this is not possible this way, and hosts must be defined before execution  in playbook hosts variable, Ansible does not support this, correct?

Inventory file, in ini format:

```ini
[all]
group1
group2
group3

[group1]
host01
host02

[group2]
host03
host04


[group3]
host05
host06
```

playbook.yml

```yaml
---
- hosts: group1
```

I made research on the web and it looks Ansible does not support this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this because `vars_prompt` happens before the host selection.

So, a playbook like this is definitely something possible:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ selected_group }}"
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: selected_group
      prompt: Which group do you want to act on?
      private: false

  tasks:
    - debug:
```

On my setup, it would yield:

```
Which group do you want to act on?: nodes

PLAY [nodes] *************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [ansible-node-2] => 
  msg: Hello world!
ok: [ansible-node-1] => 
  msg: Hello world!
```